# When generating type 3 UUIDs (nameUUID) from urls can the output set be expected to have a uniform distribution?

Tags: java, distribution, uuid

When generating type 3 UUIDs from urls (using Java's nameUUIDFromBytes) can the output set be expected to have a uniform or near uniform distribution?

Comment: If you are asking this question it probably means that you have read the relevant javadoc; if yes, how does it _not_ answer your question? Ie, can you elaborate?

Comment: The java doc just says: "Static factory to retrieve a type 3 (name based) UUID based on the specified byte array." The relevant RFC [link(https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#page-13) in section 4.3 does not mention how uniform the distribution should be, just that similar inputs should generate very different outputs (to a very high probability)

Comment: With only 3 outcomes in a 128-bit sample space, how could you tell?  I'd be suspicious of 3 consecutive values, but the javadoc implies that that won't happen.

Comment: @pjs Sorry if the question was unclear, I've generated several million "type 3" uuids, and they do not seem to have a uniform distribution. But that could just be, as you say, that my sample size is too small.

Comment: With a million, you have plenty of sample size.  Try a [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov–Smirnov_test) or [Cramér–von_Mises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramér–von_Mises_criterion) test for uniformity.